# High memory utilization due to autoflushing log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, unicorn, production, autoflush

Is it possible to have high memory utilization if `autoflush_log` is set to true?

I have a custom production environment(staging) setup like this

```
require Rails.root.join("config/environments/production")

Calamus::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:protocol => 'https', :host => xx.xx.xx.xx }
end
```

This was logging the sql statements. so I set the log level to info

```
config.log_level = :info
```

But adding the above line resulted in unicorn processes taking too much memory and the machine was running very high on memory

When I added this line

```
config.autoflush_log = false
```

The memory utilization became normal.
Can anyone see the connection? Why would `autoflushing` cause high memory utilization?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage?  What is the difference in the memory usage between `config.autoflush_log = false` and `config.autoflush_log = true`?  Setting `config.autoflush_log = true` should slightly increase CPU activity, but should reduce memory usage slightly by not buffering the output.  Unless you have a high activity application the change should be very minimal.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, writing to files is an expensive operation as any IO operation. This leads to other questions such as, how much am I logging to cause system slowdown? What file system am I logging to, is it shared, etc?

Have you looked at the logs? Are there exceptions being raised? How big does your log grow? And at what rate?

First, I would look at what's being logged, and the rate at which this is happening.
Second, if logging is normal but mem utilization is high, I would bring logging down to further investigate.

Fist. Only log anything above or equal to a warning

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

without setting autoflush_log.

When the system is high, I would look at what "top" tells me as well as /var/log/syslog

An alternative utility to "top" is "htop". It gives you more info I find (easier on the eyes) as well as being highly configurable.
http://hisham.hm/htop/